# In JavaScript, how to split the string "aa,bb\\,cc,dd" by comma but only when the previous character is not backslash?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split, regex-lookarounds

I have a string `aa,bb\\,cc,dd`. I need to split it by comma but only when the previous character is not backslash. So what I want is:

```
aa
bb\\,cc
dd
```

Since JavaScript regular expression doesn't support negative look back, I want to know how to solve it in this case. Thank you.

Comment: Actually [a few modern browsers do support lookbehind assertions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex for `match`:

```
/(?=.)([^,\\]*(?:\\.[^,\\]*)*)(?:,|$)/gm
```

This regex ignores all escaped characters while matching substrings that have a comma or end of line at next positions.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/34H5IB/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?=.)`: Make sure we don't match empty strings
- `([^,\\]*`: Match 0 or more of any chars that are not `,` and `\`
- `(?:\\.[^,\\]*)*)`: Match `\` followed by escaped character and then 0 or more of any chars that are not `,` and `\`.
- `(?:,|$)`: Match comma or end of line

```js
const regex = /(?=.)([^,\\]*(?:\\.[^,\\]*)*)(?:,|$)/gm;
const str = `aa,bb\\,cc,dd`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}

//=> [aa, bb\,cc, dd]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split by comma with a lookbehind assertion, you can split by all commas and then enforce the lookbehind assertion in a `.reduce()` while accumulating the array.

```js
const str = 'aa,bb\\,cc,dd'
const values = str.split(/,/g).reduce((acc, str) => {
  const lastIndex = acc.length - 1

  if (lastIndex >= 0 && acc[lastIndex].endsWith('\\')) {
    acc[lastIndex] += str
  } else {
    acc.push(str)
  }

  return acc
}, [])

console.log(values)
```